# How to delete a faulty FTP connection in Aptana?

Tags: aptana-studio

I just created an FTP connection in Aptana in which I made a mistake. I told Aptana to remember it anyway while I looked up the correct data (user/password and such).

Now I want to edit the FTP connection but as soon as I click it tries to connect which results in an error.
If I try to delete it, same story, it tries to connect and I get the error and the delete doesn't go through.

So, I have a non working FTP connection that I can't delete nor edit.How do I get rid of this thing? Or how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the connection from your File View. To change the connection, right-click the connection and select Properties from the context menu.

Here you can change anything you would need to change.

Comment: Thank you,
it worked after I changed my settings for selecting a file from single click to double click. When it was still on single click, it would start making a connection immediately and I'd never get the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Aptana made it impossible to find, but here is your answer.

1. Cick 'Window', from top navigation
2. Click 'Show View' -> Remote
3. You will see a remote tab next to App explorer.
4. Right click on an of the connection and select 'Properties'.
5. You can also delete the connections from this view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Connection Manager" that you can delete it (I can't find it).
I found one way to delete old or faulty FTP connection (let's say it's 'connection123').

1. Create new Web Project (or choose existing)
2. Click right on 'Connections' and select 'Connection Manager'
3. Click green '+' and change name for example 'Name1'; in 'Source' choose 'Project'; in 'Destination' choose 'Remote' and select connection (our 'connection123') that you want to modify or delete; Apply or OK
4. Under 'Connection' in Project Explorer View our Connection appear ('connection123')
5. Click right on 'connection123' and choose 'Delete'

IT'S DONE! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you input Mateusz, but to be quite honest, I didn't like Aptana and so I stopped using it. I hope this will help other Aptana users though.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/view/edit the connection by going to Window -> Show View -> Remote

[image]